# Error when printing out searches for word in a text file using string

Tags: c, string, strstr

I have my code using Visual Basic:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *inputFile = NULL;
    char line[9999];
    char word[9999];
    int count = 1;
    char *result;

    inputFile = fopen("some_text.txt", "r");

    printf("Enter the target string: ");
    scanf("%s", word);

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, inputFile) != NULL) {
        result = strstr(line, word);
        if (result != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d. %s\n", count, line);
        }
        count++;
    }

    fclose(inputFile);

    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to find the words "men of", the program gives one string that does not contain the words "men of" at all

[image]

Comment: the second paragraph (line 5) has no word "men of"

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't mean "Visual Basic"? Did you mean "Visual Studio" maybe?

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` doesn't scan `men of` it just scans `men`.
You should be using `fgets()` to scan `men of`.

`fgets()` comes with a newline character.

You have to get rid of the newline character before passing it to `strstr()`:

```
fgets(line, sizeof line, inputFile);
size_t n = strlen(line);
if (n > 0 && line[n - 1] == '\n')
{
   line[n - 1] = '\0';
}
```

The same goes for the string which you read using `fgets()`.